# Error trying to swap through balancer pool

Tags: erc-20

I am trying to exchange tokens through Balancer pools through the swapExactAmountIn function, and I have encountered some issues. Whilst executing the function on a big pool such as the WETH / DAI one, the trade executes fine. On the other hand, executing the function on a pool with less liquidity will revert without giving an error. MinAmountOut and maxPrice parameters were set correctly.

Why can't i swap in such pools?

Thanks

Comment: `MinAmountOut and maxPrice parameters were set correctly` - what does that mean?

Comment: @goodvibration minAmountOut was set to 1, maxPrixe was set to 1000000000000000000000000000. Those parameters can't influence the reverted outcome.

Comment: Well, then you're gonna have to post all the relevant details here (contract code, web3 script code, transaction parameters, transaction hash, contract addresses, etc).

Comment: @goodvibration I am trying to do it manually from the contract first. I just need to know if a pool could "close swaps".

Comment: @goodvibration if you want i can give you the address of the pool and you can try checking why it won't let me swap.